# Функция выполняется два раза

Tags: python, django

В файле manage.py мне нужно, чтобы функция `run` выполнялась. Она выполняется, но 2 раза! Как можно решить данную проблему?

manage.py

```py
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_site.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        print('error')
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start')
    
    # функция run выполняется 2 раза
    t = Thread(target=run)
    t.start()

    print('end')
    main()
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
start
end
start
end
Performing system checks...

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 07, 2022 - 12:18:12
Django version 4.0.3, using settings 'my_site.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Comment: Какая цель этого действия?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код запускает команду, которая использует reloader, что, в свою очередь, означает, что Ваш код выполняется повторно. Если использовать --noreload при выполнении команды, проблема исчезнет.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-noreload

Comment: А возможно, чтобы django перезагружался, а функция нет?

Comment: Перепиши команду

Comment: Какую команду? Напиши, или подскажи пожалуйста